# C# WinForms: By changing between the TabControl tabs, the header text in the DataGridView overlaps

Tags: c#, winforms

In the form I have several tabs that display `datagridview` data. When changing from one tab to another, the text in the column header is overlapped with another text from another grid. When I exit the form and enter directly into that tab again, everything is normal. This only happens if I switch from one to the other. DGV colums was created from UI edior and i set fixed `width`.

**This is noramal**

[image]

**When i click on `Racuni` tab that looks like this**

[image]

**What i try**

```
dataGridview1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill; 
dataGridview1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
```

This not working.

Anyone have idea how to slove this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code on the tab switch event? That behavior doesn't seem to be an issue with the columns width, it seems more like a redraw problem, maybe causes by something happening during the tab switch.

Comment: Refresh datagridview  when tab change...for example in `Adrese` tab use `AdreseGridView1.Refresh();`

Comment: I try now but not working.

Comment: I dont have any tab switch event

Comment: When i disable `HeaderVIsualStyles` that works. But i need that to be `false`

Comment: Can you try calling `Invalidate` in the tab panes and the grids? Just trying to rule out drawing issues.